# Excessive unneeded system-invoked GC on android 2.3.5 during animation

Tags: android, animation, garbage-collection

In my app, I have a ViewSwitcher with two children like this:

```
<ViewFlipper
    android:id="@+id/galeryviewflipper"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">            
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/galeryimageview_0"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        />
    (... other stuff here)
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout>
    (... copy previous except for IDs)              
    </RelativeLayout>               
</ViewFlipper>
```

Then I'm switching gallery images (each is a photo about 800x600):

```
//(setup wanted images into ImageViews)
//then:
viewFlipper.setInAnimation(instance, R.anim.fade_in);
viewFlipper.setOutAnimation(instance, R.anim.fade_in);
viewFlipper.setDisplayedChild(nextIndex);
```

On android 2.3.4 everything goes as expected, but on 2.3.5 phone (galaxy S2), dalvik calls several times GC during animation, which results in a sloppy user experience (notice GC times and duration!).   I don't call System.gc anyhere in app explicitly.

```
05-18 21:06:56.040: D/dalvikvm(6617): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed <1K, 50% free 5447K/10695K, external 17083K/17815K, paused 30ms
05-18 21:06:56.115: D/dalvikvm(6617): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed <1K, 50% free 5447K/10695K, external 17083K/17815K, paused 30ms
05-18 21:06:56.175: D/dalvikvm(6617): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed <1K, 50% free 5447K/10695K, external 17083K/17815K, paused 31ms
05-18 21:06:56.245: D/dalvikvm(6617): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed <1K, 50% free 5447K/10695K, external 17083K/17815K, paused 30ms
05-18 21:06:56.305: D/dalvikvm(6617): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed <1K, 50% free 5447K/10695K, external 17083K/17815K, paused 31ms
05-18 21:06:56.365: D/dalvikvm(6617): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed <1K, 50% free 5447K/10695K, external 17083K/17815K, paused 30ms
05-18 21:06:56.415: D/dalvikvm(6617): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed <1K, 50% free 5447K/10695K, external 17083K/17815K, paused 32ms
```

It also does the same thing on another 2.2+ phone (not a galaxy s2), so in total on one phone no GC calls, on two other ones this happens. And, the OK phone is much less powerful than a Galaxy S2, and still displays a smooth fade in-out due to absence of GC calls during the animation. Any suggestions? Thanks for help.

It is definitely not caused by insufficient memory, on Galaxy S2 5MB is used out of 64MB heap during this process. It seems to be unrelated to the actual heap usage, it happens every time.

Comment: try running MAT on your code. Despite your claim that your device has 64M of heap, it's not likely, particularly with an older 2.3.5 model, that all of that 64M is yours to use.  You're likely sharing that memory with the OS and every other app running